# Why won't parent model get updated on Angular Directive function call?

Tags: angularjs, directive

http://jsfiddle.net/2dgzt18a/

I'm expecting the model on the parent to get updated when Enter is pressed in the input. But it does not. Output from console log looks promising, like it should do it. Do I need to use a $watch ? Doubt it, but thought I'd ask.

HTML

```
<div data-ng-app="testApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <strong>{{pkey}}</strong>
        <span data-test-directive 
              data-parent-item="pkey" 
              data-parent-update="update(pkey)"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

DIRECTIVE

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.directive('testDirective', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            key: '=parentItem',
            parentUpdate: '&'
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><input type="text"></input></div>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
           elem.bind('keydown keypress', function(event) {
              if (event.which === 13) {
                  scope.parentUpdate({ pkey: 'D+' + scope.key});
                  event.preventDefault();
              }
           })
        }
    };
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
testApp.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.pkey = 'golden';
    $scope.update = function (k) {
        // Expecting local variable k, or $scope.pkey to have been
        // updated by calls in the directive's scope.
        console.log('CTRL:', $scope.pkey, k);
        $scope.pkey = 'C+' + k;
        console.log('CTRL:', $scope.pkey);
    };
});
```

I believe I have seen this work using a controller in a directive, but since I'm interested in a Keypress event, is why I need to use link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elem.bind` just binds js function to event, nothing else.

Add `scope.$apply()`.

P.S. i.e. ng-click does nearly the same: binds event and call apply after callback.

P.S.1. If you can use more modern angular version - there are `ng-keypress` and similar directives.

Answer (score -2):

scope.$apply is not preferred to use. It is better to use $timeout

> The $timeout does not generate error like „$digest already in
>   progress“ because $timeout tells Angular that after the current cycle,
>   there is a timeout waiting and this way it ensures that there will not
>   any collisions between digest cycles and thus output of $timeout will
>   execute on a new $digest cycle